# Why are there all of these other tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Excuse me but I am very new at learning to use oracle and sql.

I was given a bat file by my teacher that runs an sql to setup a database. The sql basically just drops 5 tables and recreates them with data.

What I don't understand is why I am seeing tons of other tables (that came with oracle?)

Why am I seeing all of these tables https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOlTA.jpg

the only tables that are supposed to be created are 
REP
CUSTOMER
ORDERS
PART
ORDER_LINE

Is there a way to only display those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other tables are tables Oracle uses.

Whether you see them or not depends on your permissions in the database. Ask your teacher to show you how to reduce your permissions so that you can only see the five tables your supposed to or look at the Oracle documentation here [User Admin](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admusers.htm).

ETA : Be careful if you do start messing with permissions.

Comment: Thanks that helped. In the SQL he actually created a new user with limited rights. So i just had to change the connection to that user.